# Dir()<>"" returning False even though folder exists (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word, directory

I'm running VBA in Word 2016 on Windows 10.

In trying to debug a larger sub, I created a sub after suspecting that there was some issue with the Dir function.

This debugging sub is :

```
Sub TestDetectFolder() 'with trailing backslash or not

MsgBox Dir("C:\Users\adres\Downloads\Captures") <> ""

End Sub
```

Now I literally copy/pasted the "Captures" folder's address from Explorer and still, the message box displays "False".
Since the folder exists, shoudln't it return True ?

I've also tried adding a trailing backslash, which doesn't work either

Comment: When you try to check a Directory existence you should 'tell' that to VBA.. Plase, try `MsgBox Dir("C:\Users\adres\Downloads\Captures", vbDirectory) <> ""`

Comment: Another option if you are going after the files there: `MsgBox Dir("C:\Users\adres\Downloads\Captures\*.*") <> ""`

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function#:~:text=Default)%20Specifies%20files%20with%20no%20attributes.   The default for the `attributes` parameter if not given an argument is `vbNormal`  "Specifies *files* with no attributes."